# How to convert the foreach loop to linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, if-statement, foreach

Code:

```
           foreach (var item in testItems.Distinct())
            {
                if (!testMap.ContainsKey(item.GetId()))
                {
                    testMap.Add(item.GetId(), item);
                }
            }
```

How to convert the foreach loop to linq for the above code? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to LINQ? It isn't a query... also: what is `testMap` ?

Comment: `testMap` is a dictionary? Have you considered using a set?

Comment: @astef, Yes, `testMap` is the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the correct approach to "converting {x} to LINQ" is: don't. It isn't an appropriate tool for every job. Your current code with `foreach` and dictionary mutation is fine as it is. Keep it.

If duplicate ids (after the `Distinct()`) aren't an issue, you could perhaps do:

```
var map = testItems.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.GetId());
```

But that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
testItems.ToList().ForEach(item=>
{
 if (!testMap.ContainsKey(item.GetId()))
 {
   testMap.Add(item.GetId(), item);
 }
});
```

Comment: It is questionable whether that is actually a useful use of LINQ - or even whether it is really LINQ at all... Ultimately, it is *basically* identical to the code in the original question, except without the distinct, with an extra `ToList()`, and with a lot of extra delegate indirection.

Comment: @Marc , I aggree, i have never come across such a trivial use of linq before.

Answer (score 0):

For a 1 line version, you could try this:

```
testItems.Distinct().Where(i => !testMap.ContainsKey(i.GetId()).ForEach(f => testMap.Add(f.GetId, f));
```

That will do the whole operation in one line, although I am not a big fan of doing everything at once as it can be harder to debug.